# Multiple Google maps on one page with polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have managed to build some a function that builds 4 maps that all share the same center coordinates, and there is an array of LngLat values that plot out the polylines.

The issue that i am having, for this demo is that i cannot apply the array of polylines across the 4 maps, it automatically applies them to the last instance of the map.

HTML Segment

```
<span id="mapPlaceholder" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></span>
<span id="mapPlaceholder_2" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></span>
<span id="mapPlaceholder_3" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></span>
<span id="mapPlaceholder_4" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></span>
```

Javascipt Segment

```
    function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.4488017, -3.0171732),
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    draggable: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder'),
      mapOptions);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder_2'),
      mapOptions);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder_3'),
      mapOptions);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder_4'),
      mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.455004, -3.029325),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.454587, -3.028024),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453911, -3.027952),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453537, -3.028260),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453645, -3.027656),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453414, -3.026795),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453272, -3.026101),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453503, -3.025109),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453171, -3.022341),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.452607, -3.020664),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.452233, -3.017000),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.449940, -3.015895),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.447637, -3.015378),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.445568, -3.014790),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.444773, -3.013814),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.443881, -3.015693),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.444737, -3.019457),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.446439, -3.021170),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.448048, -3.024403),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.449299, -3.027044),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.450360, -3.029291),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.452475, -3.030792),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453217, -3.029111),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.454128, -3.029341),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.455004, -3.029325)
  ];

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 4 unique map variables and 4 unique google.maps.Polyline objects, setting one on each map (a polyline only has a single map property, so it can only be on one map).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qe2fn8mr/)

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.4488017, -3.0171732),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    draggable: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder'),
    mapOptions);

  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder_2'),
    mapOptions);

  var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder_3'),
    mapOptions);

  var map4 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapPlaceholder_4'),
    mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.455004, -3.029325),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.454587, -3.028024),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453911, -3.027952),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453537, -3.028260),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453645, -3.027656),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453414, -3.026795),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453272, -3.026101),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453503, -3.025109),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453171, -3.022341),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.452607, -3.020664),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.452233, -3.017000),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.449940, -3.015895),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.447637, -3.015378),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.445568, -3.014790),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.444773, -3.013814),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.443881, -3.015693),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.444737, -3.019457),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.446439, -3.021170),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.448048, -3.024403),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.449299, -3.027044),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.450360, -3.029291),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.452475, -3.030792),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.453217, -3.029111),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.454128, -3.029341),
    new google.maps.LatLng(54.455004, -3.029325)
  ];

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
  var flightPath2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map2,
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  var flightPath3 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map3,
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  var flightPath4 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map4,
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapPlaceholder" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></div>

<div id="mapPlaceholder_2" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></div>

<div id="mapPlaceholder_3" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></div>

<div id="mapPlaceholder_4" style="height:150px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring at this for hours. Just to clarify, as eventually i'll be using this to dynamically, is there a way to loop through every instance of a polyline array to apply to multiple maps in a similar fashion? Kind of a method of setting global polyline settings such as the stroke, color etc

Comment: Sure. The simplest was is to use an array of map objects and an array of polyline objects.  There are a couple of questions out there about dynamically creating multiple maps.

Comment: Here are two questions about adding multiple maps to a single page, there are probably more: [Adding multiple map canvases to window - Google Maps Javascript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919121/adding-multiple-map-canvases-to-window-google-maps-javascript-api-v3), [Google Maps API v3 - creating multiple maps with markers on one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958837/google-maps-api-v3-creating-multiple-maps-with-markers-on-one-page)