# Is it possible to add unknown number of google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is my code.

```
 $('.google-map').each(function(index, el){
        window.initMap = function() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7483624, -73.9900896);
            var options = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: latlng
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(el, options);
        } });
```

it's working only if there is only one map object.

Comment: because you overwrite  `window.initMap` on every iteration

Comment: Yes. You just need to create the container (`<div>`) dynamically and instantiate an individual new `google.maps.Map` for each.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding multiple map canvases to window - Google Maps Javascript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919121/adding-multiple-map-canvases-to-window-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 - creating multiple maps with markers on one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958837/google-maps-api-v3-creating-multiple-maps-with-markers-on-one-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you loop over the jQuery collection and override the `initMap` on every iteration. Instead of trying to do that in the loop, wait for initMap and than do your loop.

```
window.initMap = function() {
   $('.google-map').each(function(index, el) {
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7483624, -73.9900896);
     var options = {
       zoom: 14,
       center: latlng
     }
     var map = new google.maps.Map(el, options);
   });
 }
```

Comment: You don't need the `var map` at all, since it's not used anywhere and goes out of scope immediately.